# Quick search in NAS. Which software for overview?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, search, nas

We use a NAS in our small company to acces our files from different locations. Searching within the NAS does not work well due to the amount of data stored and slow internet connection. So if we're looking for a file, we need to know exactly where it is.

I do not need a NAS-side solution since the operating system of the NAS is very inflexible.

Is there a way to keep an up-to-date overview of the complete folder/file struture (as text, tree, table, whatever) in which we can quickly search for the files?

Comment: If you are looking for a NAS-side solution, AD might not be the best place to ask

Comment: Hi... Nope, looking for a Mac solution. It's a WD MyCloud wih a horrible interface, no chance to do it at the NAS side.

Comment: Closely related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394431/is-there-an-app-like-spotlight-that-can-index-external-drives-and-return-searc

Comment: have you considered just using `find` and `tree` in the Terminal? Seems like the easiest way. Likely will want to mount the NAS locally. Alternatively could try to ssh into the NAS box and run it there but then it would become a NAS-side action. I would just get some dedicated device to run a `crontab` that does something like `find /Volumes/NAS -type f > /Volumes/NAS/index.txt` every day or so. You can then easily Ctrl+F or `grep` the .txt index file. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

With having 30+ TB of external storage I find it absolutely necessary to manage it in some way, and for that I use a paid app named [**DiskCatalogMaker**](https://diskcatalogmaker.com) to keep a database of everything I have on external disks.

It does have a free 30 day evaluation, but it's $38.99 USD for a single user license and $58.99 for a family license. It's bit pricy but after using the eval I bit the bullet and paid the price and wouldn't want to not have it now.

<sub>Note: I'm not affiliated with the developer of the product, just a very satisfied user.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This solution is vexing and hard to solve generally.

We have had great success with one product and have tried many, none seem to work well as they don’t solve the remote index and then share that index out nail on the head.

- https://cdfinder.de/

The marketing calls it the holy grail of media asset management, and I think that’s a little bit of an understatement. It does more than just that, it scales and is extensible and you can automate on top of it.

As you mention, the indexing would have to run on naps to be perpetually up to date, but periodic index scans by NeoFinder work well for us.